# Can numerical values be assigned to alphabetic elements of a list and then added using the sum() function?

Tags: python-3.x, list

I am  trying the following problem and I don't know what's wrong. Can somebody help me through it?

```
java=10
python=10
sql=5
unix=5
javascript=5
framework=10
i=eval(input("Enter courses done in a list"))
if sum(i)>=30:
    print("eligible since the score is", sum(i))
else:
    print("Not eligible since the score is",sum(i))
```

But I am getting the following error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/Python Notes/Python Programs/Eligible for placement.py", line 8, in <module>
    if sum(i)>=30:
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's assume that user input is a string of course names split by whitespace, then:

```
courses = {"java":10,
           "python":10,
           "sql":5,
           "unix":5,
           "javascript":5,
           "framework":10}
user_input = input("Enter courses done in a list")
course_names = user_input.split()
i = sum([courses.get(course,0) for course in course_names])
if i >= 30:
    print("eligible since the score is", i)
else:
    print("Not eligible since the score is",i)
```

Comment: I am just starting out, I don't understand the 8th and 9th line. Can you explain the two lines?

Comment: @RajkumarMaurya, Google "python list comprehension" for the first. For the second, try to come up with a Google search string by looking at the type of the argument and the method that was called. While SO is here to help, there is a level of homework that is expected of each of us before asking for other people's time.

Comment: @RajkumarMaurya 8th line is to split the user input by whitespace and it returns a Python list. For example, if you type `python unix java`, it returns `["python", "unix", "java"]`. 9th line is list comprehension which is used to generate a list containing scores. Then use `sum` to get the sum of the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

you can try with setting a string as a variable name

```
java=10
python=10
sql=5
unix=5
javascript=5
framework=10
i=input("Enter courses done in a list:").split() # ['python', 'java', 'sql']
sum_ = 0

for item in i:
    sum_ += int(vars()[item]) # "use string like a variable"

if sum_>=30:
    print("eligible since the score is ", sum_)
else:
    print("Not eligible since the score is ",sum_)
```

output:

```
Enter courses done in a list:python java sql
Not eligible since the score is  25
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but open with saying you should never just `eval()` raw user input. It looks like you've manually entered strings, or a variable that stores a string, at your own prompt, since the error message is saying that, on line 8 (`if sum(i)>=30:`) that the `+` operator can't work with both strings and integers at the same time. For example, `sum('foo', 1)` gives the same error.

Check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . It's just as good for OPs as it is for responders.